# Android Studio Kotlin how to make a Constraint Layout scrollable with Scroll View?

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, scrollview

Basically I want to make the screen scrollable when the keyboard appears during text input, but no matter what I do it refuses to work. I made a Scroll View and put a Constraint Layout with all the elements in it. But it just refuses to scroll when the keyboard pops up.

This is the .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_purple"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_top_left_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/top_left_illustration_login_screen"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_top_right_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/top_right_illustration_login_screen"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_triangle_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="181dp"
            android:src="@drawable/triangle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Shows"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/IV_triangle_login"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="178dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TIL_password_login"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_login"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/ET_password_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:maxLength="25"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TIL_email_login"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/TIL_password_login"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/ET_email_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:maxLength="35"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ET_please_log_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="In order to continue please log in"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/TIL_email_login"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ET_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ET_please_log_in"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_login_toggled_on"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color_login"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

and this is how the activity looks like

[image]

I feel like the constraint to the button (bottom to bottom of parent) could be an issue. I enabled the fillViewport because without it it's broken. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try making the `ConstraintLayout`'s height `wrap_content` - the `ScrollView` is like a window, so you don't want the stuff on the inside to be the same height as that window (or there's nothing extra to scroll). Also make

Comment: This didn't help :(

Comment: Have you read this? https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#Respond You might want to set it to `adjustPan` (and you might not need the `ScrollView` at all, if it's only there for this keyboard situation)

Comment: I tried all of that. No changes I make to the android manifest do anything. The ONLY thing that "works" is creating an element way below the screen. Then it scrolls normally but it deforms my layout.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding this attribute to the scroll view:
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"